# The best way for switching theme?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, switching

Currently im working in an app that includes a dark theme, but how it should be, should I toggle the class (the one with dark color) or only change the value of a CSS property?

In other project I used a JS function to toggle some css classes, but the css code grew up much, this time I coded in the other way:

```
const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
let theme = "dark";
const callbackThemeF = function () {   
    if(theme === "dark"){
        rootElement.style.setProperty('--elements-background-color', "blue");
        theme = "light";
    }
    else if (theme === "light"){
        rootElement.style.setProperty('--elements-background-color', "BLACK");
        theme = "dark";
    }

}
```

the CSS var `'--elements-background-color'` is used in some components, when the function is triggered it works properly but it's correct to do it this way?

I'm working with ReactJS

Comment: Also consider [letting users set their theme using their system preference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme)

Comment: If legacy browser compat isn’t required, I would go with css var solution. You can also toggle class, where the class applies a set of themed css vars, instead if a set if fixed rules.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts yeah, but that only works with de OS right?
I need to have a button for thar purpose, not all devices have a native dark mode integrated

Comment: @VictorAlfonsoPérezEspino you can do both, just make sure your theme-specific CSS is targeted using both the media query in my link and the class you choose to use for applying the alternate styling.